# Python Mocking in Complex Class Structure

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-unittest

I am writing a unit test (with mocking) that looks like this,

```
def test_1(self):
    # define the chat data to return
    chat_data = {
        '@odata.context': 'test_context',
        'id': 'test_id',
        'topic': None,
        'createdDateTime': '2023-11-20T10:25:19.553Z',
        'lastUpdatedDateTime': '2023-11-20T10:25:19.553Z',
        'chatType': 'oneOnOne',
        'webUrl': 'https://teams.test',
        'tenantId': 'test_tenant_id',
        'onlineMeetingInfo': None,
        'viewpoint': {
            'isHidden': False,
            'lastMessageReadDateTime': '2023-12-08T17:09:34.214Z'
        },
        'lastMessagePreview@odata.context': 'https://graph.test',
        'lastMessagePreview': {
            'id': '1702055374214',
            'createdDateTime': '2023-12-08T17:09:34.214Z',
            'isDeleted': False,
            'messageType': 'message',
            'eventDetail': None,
            'body': {
                'contentType': 'text',
                'content': '\n\nTest message.'
            },
            'from': {
                'application': None,
                'device': None,
                'user': {}
            }
        }
    }

    # mock the api handler
    api_handler = Mock(MSTeamsHandler)
    with patch.object(api_handler.connect(), 'get_chat', return_value=chat_data):
        chats_table = ChatsTable(api_handler)

        # the rest of my test logic
```

This works fine, however, right now, I am testing the `get_chat` function of the object that is returned by `api_handler.connect()`, but what I actually want to mock is the `requests.get()` call that is made to the API. This is done via the `get_chat` function.

This is what those functions look like within the class,

```
Class Client:
    def _make_request(self, api_url: str, params: Optional[Dict] = None, data: Optional[Dict] = None, method: str = "GET") -> Union[Dict, object]:
        headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {self.access_token}"}
        if method == "GET":
            response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers, params=params)
        elif method == "POST":
            response = requests.post(api_url, headers=headers, json=data)
        else:
            raise NotImplementedError(f"Method {method} not implemented")
        if response.status_code == 429:
            if "Retry-After" in response.headers:
                pause_time = float(response.headers["Retry-After"])
                time.sleep(pause_time)
                response = requests.get(api_url, headers=headers, params=params)
        if response.status_code not in [200, 201]:
            raise requests.exceptions.RequestException(response.text)
        if response.headers["Content-Type"] == "application/octet-stream":
            raw_response = response.content
        else:
            raw_response = response.json()
        return raw_response

  def get_chat(self, chat_id: Text) -> Dict:
    """
    Get a chat by its ID.

    Parameters
    ----------
    chat_id : str
        The ID of the chat.
    """

    api_url = self._get_api_url(f"chats/{chat_id}")
    # expand the response with the last message preview
    chat = self._make_request(api_url, params={"$expand": "lastMessagePreview"})

    return chat
```

How can I mock the `requests.get()` call in `_make_request()` instead?

Comment: There are many great options for request mocking using pytest plugins. Some popular ones are [requests-mock](https://pypi.org/project/requests-mock), [responses](https://pypi.org/project/responses), and my personal favorite: [pook](https://pypi.org/project/pook).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to patch `requests.get` instead you can make it return a mock response with the expected status code, headers and JSON content:

```
with patch(
    'requests.get',
    return_value=Mock(
        status_code=200,
        headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        json=Mock(return_value=chat_data)
    )
):
    chats_table = ChatsTable(api_handler)
    ...
```

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. The response I get from `get_chat` after this is: `[<Mock name='mock.con...00906320'>]`